# how to decrypt in angular 5 while data encypted using crypto.js in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, cryptojs

I have encrypted some Text using following code in express.js:-

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
password = '6A80FD8D38D579D1090F6CDB62CA34CA',
iv = '79b67e539e7fcadf';

var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm,password,iv)
var crypted = cipher.update('hello world','utf8','hex')
crypted += iv.toString('hex') + cipher.final('hex');
console.log(crypted)
```

And now, I wanted to decrypt this encryptedText in angular 5. But I am not able to found any way to do this. I try following code:-

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('6A80FD8D38D579D1090F6CDB62CA34CA');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('79b67e539e7fcadf');

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedTextHere, key, {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,
});
```

Any help in getting the correct code is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
import { AES, enc, mode } from 'crypto-js';

const key = enc.Utf8.parse('6A80FD8D38D579D1090F6CDB62CA34CA');
const iv = enc.Utf8.parse('79b67e539e7fcadf');

const decrypted = AES.decrypt('encryptedTextHere', key, {
  iv: iv,
  mode: mode.CTR
});
console.log(decrypted.toString(enc.Utf8));
```

Also make sure to install the typings

```
npm i @types/crypto-js --save-dev
```

Comment: give me your `encryptedText`  so that i can test from my side

Comment: thanks to reply,my encrypted data is : "a03a07a262460fd63d3cdbcc06b5900cf854df966cdf2b271ced8b79b67e539e7fcadf" and i also install @types/crypto-js but it's not woking